# How to style a single element made by using map

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm making a calculator app in react-native. I'm creating calculator buttons with map funtion but of course every single button looks the same is there a way to change style for a single element or should i change the way the buttons are created. This is my "sample" button

```
import React, {Component} from "react"; 
import { StyleSheet, Text , TouchableOpacity, } from "react-native";
    
    
    export default class InputButton extends React.Component{
        render() {
    
            const{value,handleOnPress} = this.props;
    
        return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.container}
                    onPress={()=> handleOnPress(value)}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>{value}</Text>
    
                </TouchableOpacity>
    
        );
        } }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create(
        {
            container:{
                flex:1,
                margin: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                justifyContent:"center",
                alignItems: 'center'
            },
    
            text:{
                fontSize: 30,
                color: 'white',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
    
        });
```

And that's my function in main component that return entire layout of buttons:

```
renderButtons = () =>{

       console.log(SCREEN_WIDTH + " " + SCREEN_HEIGHT)

      if(SCREEN_HEIGHT > SCREEN_WIDTH){

        let layouts = buttons.map((buttonRows,index)=>{
            let rowItem = buttonRows.map((buttonItems,buttonIndex)=>{
                return <InputButton
                value={buttonItems}
                handleOnPress={handleInput.bind(buttonItems)}
                key={'btn-'+ buttonIndex}/>
            });
            return <View style={styles.inputRow} key={'row-' + index}>{rowItem}</View>
        });

        return layouts
      }

      
      else 
      {
        let layouts = buttons_landscape.map((buttonRows,index)=>{
          let rowItem = buttonRows.map((buttonItems,buttonIndex)=>{
              return <InputButton
              value={buttonItems}
              handleOnPress={handleInput.bind(buttonItems)}
              key={'btn-'+ buttonIndex}/>
          });
          return <View style={styles.inputRow} key={'row-' + index}>{rowItem}</View>
      });

      return layouts

      }
    }
```

I'm using these array to make the button layouts:

```
const buttons = [
    ['AC','DEL'],
    ['7','8','9','/'],
    ['4','5','6','-'],
    ['1','2','3','*'],
    ['0','.','=',,'+']
];

const buttons_landscape = [
  ['DEL','x!','e','+/-','%','AC'],
  ['10^x','√','2','8','9','/'],
  ['log10','e^x','4','5','6','-'],
  ['x^2','ln','1','2','3','*'],
  ['x^3','π','0','.','=','+']
];
```

And my question is how can I change the way that I create the buttons and layouts so that every sigle one has unique properties OR change the style of singular button

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, replace

```
return <View style={styles.inputRow} key={'row-' + index}>{rowItem}</View>
```

with something along those lines

```
return <View style={someFunction(buttonItems, buttonIndex)} key={'row-' + index}>{rowItem}</View>
```

where `someFunction` return the expected style (defaulting to `styles.inputRow`, I guess).

(Also, is your `else` block almost identical with the `if` block, the only difference being `buttons` v. `buttons_landscape`? It would be better if it accepted buttons as argument, instead of repeating the same 8 lines of code).

Comment: Yes, it is the same xD I just tried to make it work quick and didn't change it

Answer (score 0):

You could break `RowItem` out into its own component and provide styles as if it were an individual row item, then map the results to an instance of the `RowItem`.

```
function RowItem() {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={xxx}
      className="xxx"
    >
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

function Buttons() {
  return (
    <table>
     <thead>
       ...
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      {props.buttons.map((button) => (
       <RowItem button={button} key={button.id} />
       )
      }
     </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```